# Redefining \section with titlesec using \clearpage causes extra entries in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec

The following MWE shows that whenever I issue a `\clearpage` within the redefinition of `\section`, it produces an additional entry in the table of contents. Why does this happen? And how should I fix it? I want to keep the `explicit` key to `titlesec`, and I'd still like to be able to pagebreak during my redefinition of `\section`.

```
\documentclass{extbook}
\makeatletter
\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}%
\titleformat{name=\section}{}{}{\z@}
  {\clearpage}
  [\clearpage]
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First section}
\subsection{This is a section}
\subsection{This is another section}
\section{A section}
\subsection{Another section}
\subsection{One more section}
\end{document}
```

---

```
\documentclass{extbook}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}%
\usepackage{changepage}
\makeatletter
\titleformat{name=\section}
  {}
  {}
  {\z@}
  {%
   \ifnum\c@page=1
     \thispagestyle{empty}%
     \clearpage
   \else
     \clearpage
     \checkoddpage
     \ifoddpage
       \null\clearpage
   \fi\fi
   \thispagestyle{empty}%
     {\Huge%
      #1}%
   \vskip10pt
   {\normalsize\itshape Some box}%
  }
  [\clearpage
  \null
  \vskip20pt
  ]
\titlespacing*{\section}{\z@}{\z@}{\z@}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Magnetism}
\subsection{This is a section}
\subsection{This is another section}
\section{The Hubbard Model}
\subsection{Another section}
\subsection{One more section}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a pagebreak before a section you need to define `\sectionbreak` and set the class of the `\section` to `top`. Then remove the `\clearpage` commands from your `\titleformat`.

```
\documentclass{extbook}
\makeatletter
\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}%
\titleclass{\section}{top}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
\titleformat{name=\section}{}{}{\z@}
  {#1}
  []
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First section}
\subsection{This is a section}
\subsection{This is another section}
\section{A section}
\subsection{Another section}
\subsection{One more section}
\end{document}
```

But as you note, this doesn't allow you to have a `\clearpage` after the section title.  I have no idea why this behaviour arises, (perhaps it's a bug in `titlesec`) but there is definitely a workaround, which is to redefine `\section` so that the page break is issued after it.

```
\documentclass{extbook}
\makeatletter
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}%
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{%
\ifnum\c@page=1
     \thispagestyle{empty}%
     \clearpage
   \else
     \clearpage
     \checkoddpage
     \ifoddpage
       \null\clearpage
   \fi\fi
}
\titleclass{\section}{top}
\usepackage{changepage}
\titleformat{name=\section}
  {}
  {}
  {\z@}
  {%
   \thispagestyle{empty}%
     {\Huge%
      #1}%
   \vskip10pt
   {\normalsize\itshape Some box}%
  }
  []
\titlespacing*{\section}{\z@}{\z@}{\z@}
\makeatother
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\oldsection}{\section}
\renewcommand{\section}[2][]{%
   \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
     \oldsection{#2}
   \else\oldsection[#1]{#2}
   \fi
   \vspace{\fill}\par\pagebreak\null\vskip20pt}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section[This is TOC]{Magnetism}
\subsection{This is a section}
\subsection{This is another section}
\section{The Hubbard Model}
\subsection{Another section}
\subsection{One more section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any way to retain the fine control of *where* the `\clearpage` occurs within the redefinition of `\section`? I agree that this fixes the MWE, but I can't control where the page break is happening.

Comment: This was exactly my answer (before I deleted it since it doesn't provide the \clearpage after the title.)

Comment: @1010011010 Where do you want the page break to be?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I can delete my answer then if you want to resurrect yours.

Comment: No, no. I just wanted to mention the issue with the final clearpage.

Comment: @AlanMunn I want material before and after the page break in `\section`, but this only allows for pagebreaks directly before and after the section, but nowhere else. Hold on while I write up an MWE.

Comment: @AlanMunn Check updated question.

Comment: @1010011010 Yes, the problem is the same, effectively. The issue really is why you can't put a `\clearpage` in the after code. All your before code `\clearpage` stuff can be put into the definition of `\sectionbreak`.

Comment: @1010011010 I've updated my answer with a solution, but not an answer to your *why does it happen* question.

Answer (score 2):

Penalties, marks and the like must be properly synchronized with page breaks. This why `\sectionbreak` exists (to emit it at the right place) and also the `page` class, with a page break before and after the title:

```
\documentclass{extbook}
\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}%
\titleclass{\section}{page}
\titleformat{name=\section}{}{}{0pt}{#1}
```

The manual must make clear 'before' and 'after' are not the proper places for penalties. But there is a flaw in `titlesec`, yet - there is no direct way to set the space after the page break (at the top of the new page) or if there must be a blank page (it uses the class settings `openright` and `openany`).